# How to fix Property 'tenant' does not exist on type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, typescript

I have below request and exported this json body.

```
export const settingsReq = {
  "states": [
    {
      "initial": false,
      "style": "plain",
      "elements": [
        {
          "type": "question",
          "visible": true,
          "detail": {
            "required": false,
            "extra": {
              "spam_filter_on": true
            },
            "style": "textarea",
            "tenant": {
              "TR": "information"
            }
          },
          "key": "P2E1",
          "triggers": null
        },
        {
          "type": "submit",
          "visible": true,
          "tenant": {
            "TR": "test"
          },
          "key": "P2E2",
          "detail": null,
          "triggers": null
        }
      ],
      "key": "P2"
    },
    {
      "initial": false,
      "style": "thank",
      "elements": [
        {
          "type": "label",
          "visible": true,
          "tenant": {
            "TR": "Thanks everyone"
          },
          "key": "P3E1",
          "detail": null,
          "triggers": null
        }
      ],
      "key": "P3"
    }
  ],
}
```

In another file I want to access **Thanks everyone** text.Used below method.

`let thanksMessage=settingsReq.states[1].elements[0].tenant.TR`

When I use below method code works no problem.But the problem is that the tenant key is underlined in red on Visual Studio Code. As I said,code works correctly even though only the tenant key is underlined(settingsReq.states[1].elements[0].**tenant**.TR). But why only the tenant key is underlined. How can I turn off tenant key's error.

Comment: What's the TS output when you hover over the tenant in your code editor?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason why the tenant key is underlined in red in Visual Studio Code is because it is not a valid JavaScript identifier, and Visual Studio Code is flagging it as a syntax error.

To access the value of the TR property, you can use the square bracket notation instead of the dot notation, like this:

```
let thanksMessage = settingsReq.states[1].elements[0].tenant['TR'];
```

This will allow you to access the TR property without causing a syntax error.

Alternatively, you can turn off the error highlighting for this specific line by adding a comment at the end of the line, like this:

```
let thanksMessage = settingsReq.states[1].elements[0].tenant.TR; // eslint-disable-line
```

This will tell ESLint to ignore the error on this line. However, this is not recommended, as it will suppress all errors on this line, not just the one related to the tenant key.

Comment: Did you generate this answer with tools like ChatGPT?

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the detail property
`let thanksMessage=settingsReq.states[1].elements[0].detail.tenant.TR`